How come I am getting an Error stating that an address is already in use in tcp client/server when all ports have been cleared prior?
I am currently attempting to use a single threaded TCP client/server programme to send a file from the client to the server, however when I attempt to do it I am met with "OSError: [Errno 98] When attempting to connect from the client side
Commands I'm using for this
./info.py -r -p 6006 -                 # server side
./info.py -t -p 6006 -ip 127.0.0.1 -   # client side

I have made sure to clear these ports prior but no matter and made sure that the ports were within the range, it still gives me the same error.
Please find below the two functions where this error is occuring
def ifTcpserver():
    serverIP = "127.0.0.1"
    serverPort = 6006

    serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverAddr = (serverIP,serverPort)
    serverSock.bind(serverAddr)
    serverSock.listen(1)
    print(f"listening on port {serverPort}")

    while True:
        connectSock, addr = serverSock.accept()
        jsonBytes = connectSock.recv(1024)
        print("data:",jsonBytes.decode("UTF-8"))
        ifDic = json.loads(jsonBytes)
        print(ifDic, type(ifDic))      
        connectSock.close()

def ifTcpclient(localInfo):
    serverIP = "127.0.0.1"
    serverPort = 6006

    jsonMessage = localInfo

    clientSocket = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockAddr = (serverIP, serverPort)
    clientSocket.connect(sockAddr)
    jsonBytes = jsonMessage.encode("UTF-8")
    clientSocket.send(jsonBytes)
    
    clientSocket.close()


@SIGHUP: if a process exits (also when killed) all sockets are closed automatically by the OS

@SteffenUllrich If you do not open the socket with SO_REUSEADDR then it can go into a TIME_WAIT state and thus be unusable (for some time). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Matters may be different on Windows but that's what I believe to be the case on Unix-like systems. Discussed here

@SIGHUP: correct, but SO_REUSEADDR has nothing to do with closing the server socket, which as I said is implicitly done on process exit. As for SO_REUSEADDR - this is exactly the answer I've linked to when closing as duplicate.
